# asp.net server side event is not working

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile

I have an button in  my Jquery mobile page, which is using asp.net webform.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSeacrh" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSeacrh_Click" />
```

Which is enabling asp:panel via this simple code on backend

```
 protected void btnSeacrh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlSearch.Visible = true;
}
```

Now, when I am clicking this button nothing happened but the URL is extended with the # keyword.

Ex. Previously it was

```
http://localhost:4989/MobileApp/CreateOrderByText.aspx
```

After clicking

```
http://localhost:4989/MobileApp/CreateOrderByText.aspx#/MobileApp/CreateOrderByText.aspx
```

But it is not showing the panel.

Any help ?

Comment: What does the form tag look like?

Comment: is pnlSearch nested inside any other server side controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted looks fine, so I would assume the problem is elsewhere: are there any javascript errors on the page?